# How to get username of person who had hit the custom build Rest API in my Java code?

Tags: java, postman, developer-tools

I am trying to build a custom build plugin using Atlassian sdk framework and in that I have developed a Rest API to fetch data saved in Active Objects database tables and I am using basic authentication in postman where I need to provide my local Jira username and password.

In my plugin code, I am storing data using active objects and following code I am using to fetch the stored data in active objects table:

```
// To delete all the rules present in database table
@DELETE
@Path("/debug/delete/rules")
public Response deleteAllRules() {

    boolean result = rules.deleteAllStoredRules();
    if (result) {
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }
    return Response.status(205).build();
}
```

Can anyone please help me to find a way to fetch username provided in basic authentication in my java code?

Comment: You should give a wider context. For example, are you using any form of authentication?

Comment: Yes, I am hitting the API's using Postman and I am using basic Authentication in postman i.e my username and password of my local Jira

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to retrieve the currently authenticated principal is via a static call to the SecurityContextHolder:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();
```

Please read more about this: https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

Comment: I tried adding above code but I am getting 500 Internal Server Error in postman with following message:                                                                                                                                             ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<status>
    <status-code>500</status-code>
    <message>org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder</message>
    <stack-trace>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder&#13;```

Comment: Your error can has a lot of reason, but first of all check when you login you set context security-> SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

Comment: I have tried adding following code, but still I am getting above error in postman:                                                                                          ```Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication); 
  String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();
  
  System.out.println("Current username: " + currentPrincipalName);```

Comment: Can you please let me know, if there is any other way to fetch username provided in basic authentication?

Comment: You need create Authentication before geting. LIke:                                                                                final Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    UserPrincipal.createUserPrincipal(loginDto),
                    loginDto.getPassword(),
                    AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(ROLE_USER)
            );  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have tried multiple ways but I am not able to get how to populate loginDto. Can you please share any guide or any references so that I can use them to get some info on the same?